# Why does Elasticsearch create snapshot for all indices when I only ask for a specific one?

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot, elasticsearch-5

I am issuing a snapshot creation command as follows:

```
curl -v -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3-backup/hospitals" -d '{\
"indices":"hospitals",\
"ignore_unavailable":true,\
"include_global_state":false\
}'
```

in order to create a snapshot named `hospitals` for the index named `hospitals`. However, when I get back the status of the index, it reports that it is creating a snapshot for all the indices. Here it is:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3-backup/hospitals"
>
{"snapshots":[{"snapshot":"hospitals","uuid":"
<uid>","version_id":5050299,"version":"5.5.2","indices":
[".kibana","super_category","professions","white_page","vertical",
"location","postal_codes","hospitals","enhanced_services",
"yellow_pages_2","listings","public_sector"],"state":"IN_PROGRESS",
"start_time":"2018-08-18T05:10:34.692Z","start_time_in_millis":1534569034692,
"end_time":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"end_time_in_millis":0,
"duration_in_millis":-1534569034692,"failures":[],"shards":
{"total":0,"failed":0,"successful":0}}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that I am using the `S3 Repository` plugin.

**Update**

@AHT asked me to post here the output of `_cut/shards`:

`vertical          0 p STARTED    27086   1.2gb <IP> prod-data-1
vertical          0 r STARTED    27086   1.3gb <IP>  prod-data-2
white_page        0 p STARTED 10579484  25.7gb <IP> prod-data-1
white_page        0 r STARTED 10579484  25.7gb <IP>  prod-data-2
professions       0 p STARTED    24425 823.4mb <IP> prod-data-1
professions       0 r STARTED    24425 823.4mb <IP>  prod-data-2
location          0 p STARTED    15048  27.2mb <IP> prod-data-1
location          0 r STARTED    15048  26.5mb <IP>  prod-data-2
enhanced_services 0 p STARTED    10385    15mb <IP> prod-data-1
enhanced_services 0 r STARTED    10385  15.7mb <IP>  prod-data-2
postal_codes      0 r STARTED    56079  32.6mb <IP> prod-data-1
postal_codes      0 p STARTED    56079  32.6mb <IP>  prod-data-2
.kibana           0 r STARTED        2   6.2kb <IP> prod-data-1
.kibana           0 p STARTED        2   6.2kb <IP>  prod-data-2
yellow_pages_2    0 p STARTED   728676   4.3gb <IP> prod-data-1
yellow_pages_2    0 r STARTED   728676   3.3gb <IP>  prod-data-2
super_category    0 r STARTED     2576   7.6mb <IP> prod-data-1
super_category    0 p STARTED     2576   7.6mb <IP>  prod-data-2
listings          0 r STARTED  2468540  21.6gb <IP> prod-data-1
listings          0 p STARTED  2468540  21.7gb <IP>  prod-data-2
public_sector     0 p STARTED    76444 741.4mb <IP> prod-data-1
public_sector     0 r STARTED    76444 733.9mb <IP>  prod-data-2
hospitals         0 r STARTED      726 281.2kb <IP> prod-data-1
hospitals         0 p STARTED      726 293.4kb <IP>  prod-data-2`

Comment: Can you post the output of  _cat/shards ?

Comment: @AHT: thank you for asking. I have posted the answer to your question.

Comment: Please post anonymous data (e.g. no need for the ips)

Comment: @AHT: Although these IPs were private, I removed them. Thank you.

Comment: What's the status now? Any luck figuring out the problem?

Comment: The snapshot creation finished successfully, but it included all the indices (and took about 26 minutes to complete). And that was my question about. Why did that include all the indices in the snapshot when I only asked for index `hospitals`.

Comment: Your curl command is absolutely correct and it should only back up the "hospitals" index. I am not sure how you set up the back up repository and your complete settings, but this source might help you: 
https://medium.com/@federicopanini/elasticsearch-backup-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-f1fc32fbca7f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178294/discussion-between-aht-and-p-matsinopoulos).